# Local notifications plugin cause the Ionic app to crash on device

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins, localnotification

I'm developing an Ionic app and I'm using Phonegap Build to build it.

I want to be able to schedule local notifications. For that reason I decided to use the following plugin:
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

Unfortunately, when I include the plugin in my config.xml, the app is crashing when I start it in the device! The weird thing is that I'm not even using the local notifications, I just included the plugin in my config.xml!

My config.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id          = "xxxxxxxxx"
        version     = "1.0.0" >

    <name>xxxxxxx</name>

    <description>
        xxxxxxxxx
    </description>

    <author href="xxxxxx" email="xxxxxx">
        xxxxxxx
    </author>

    <access origin="*"/>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>

    <preference name="orientation"                value="default" />        <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
    <preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />      <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
    <preference name="phonegap-version"           value="3.7.0" />

    <!-- IOS specific -->
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />

    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false"/>
    <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Keyboard">
        <param name="ios-package" value="IonicKeyboard" onload="true" />
    </feature>

    <platform name="ios">
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" height="1136" width="640"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" height="1334" width="750"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" height="2208" width="1242"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" height="1242" width="2208"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" height="1536" width="2048"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" height="768" width="1024"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" height="2048" width="1536"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" height="1024" width="768"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" height="960" width="640"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" height="480" width="320"/>
    </platform>

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin" version="2.4.0" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.statusbar" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.transistorsoft.cordova.background-geolocation"/>
    <gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.calendar" />
    <gap:plugin name="com.ionic.keyboard" version="1.0.3" />
    <gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" />

    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" version="0.9.0">
        <param name="APP_ID" value="xxxxxxx" />
        <param name="APP_NAME" value="xxxxxxx" />
    </gap:plugin>

</widget>
```

I should note that I'm also using ng-cordova for push notifications and facebook (and hopefully local notifications if I manage to resolve the crashing issues).

If I remove the plugin, then everything is working fine. Am I doing something wrong? Are there any conflicting dependencies?

**EDIT:**

I tried removing the plugins one by one to check which ones are causing the conflict, I found out that the problem occurs when I include the following plugins:

- org.transistorsoft.cordova.background-geolocation
- de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification

Comment: Have you tried to disable one of the other plugins to find the error?

Comment: @Joerg Good point! I tried removing one by one the rest of the plugins and it looks like the problem is with org.transistorsoft.cordova.background-geolocation and de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification!!! I'll update the question.